# Lightest docker image to run python programs

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

The only requirement is to be able to run python 3 command , i won't be installing additional packages on it. I have used alpine before and I have seen python slim , are those my best options ?
Also would appreciate of you can point out similar images for other programming languages

What I am trying to build is a simple service to which the user sends his code + input and the service executes it on respective containers(pods) running on the cluster and returns the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the alpine package because it is light and secure focused, and then you can go through the services and applications, and decide if these are not needed and remove them. Afterwards you can create another Docker image from this container.

I found a webpage which helps with efficiency of a build, by using the Docker cache more effectively, if this helps,

https://vsupalov.com/speed-up-python-docker-image-build/

The Problem
Your Dockerfile probably contains something like this:

```
ADD code /app # executed on every small change
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
# and here we go again...
```

You’re adding your project code (Flask or Django project?) after installing the necessary libraries and setting up a virtual environment. Then, you’re running pip to install the exact versions of every Python dependency needed for the project in a `“requirements.txt”` file.

You’re not using the Docker cache as well as you could. The good news is: there’s a simple way to fix that.

Use The Docker Cache
You can prevent the perpetual re-execution of the dependency-installation step if there were not actual changes to the stuff you’re using. There’s no tricky volume mounting or multi-stage build kung-fu needed.

The `ADD` directive only needs to run if the referenced file changed since the last time it was executed. If it did, every single build step needs to run again, but if it’s the same you can just use a version from the Docker cache and skip to the next one.

If you add the requirements.txt file before your other code, and run the `pip install` step right after it, both will only be executed if the file changes. Not on every build.

```
    ADD code/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
    RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
    # the steps above only depend on the requirements.txt file!
    ADD code /app
```

This way, you can skip the expensive operation if nothing changed and reuse a cached state. You Docker image build will be faster in most cases. Once that’s not enough anymore, there are more elaborate ways to improve on the process.